# Why there is no gap between rows of less than 2 images?

Tags: html, css

So I have a bunch of images inside the div and, if they do not fit into window width, they are wrapped into several rows. The part I do not understand is, why there is a gap between these rows **ONLY if there are more than 1 image in a row**?

Code:

```
<style>
img {
    width: 350px;
}
</style>
...
<div>
    <img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" />
    <img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" />
    <img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" />
    <img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" />
    <img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" />
    <img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" />
</div>
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/juterinu/3

I can see this effect in both FF and Chrome.

Comment: Include your code in the question.

Comment: This is confiusing me, in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/4brEf/1/ the whitespace doesn't disapear when there is space for only one image...

Comment: @web-tiki, it doesn't happen in _Standards mode_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because of `vertical-alignment` of an image in *Quirks mode*.

Check out these excerpts from [this page](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html):

> Vertical alignment of an image is under certain conditions to the bottom of the enclosing box, not to the baseline of text. This happens when the image is **the only content within an element**, typically a table cell. This means that e.g. an image in a table cell is by default at the bottom of the cell in Quirks Mode (which is often what the author wants), whereas in Standards Mode there is a few pixels spacing below the image (unless one sets e.g. vertical-align: bottom for the img element).

I guess, when the images are wrapped and there's only one image per line, it behaves like the image is *the only content within an element*.

And this one from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Mode_differences_and_examples):

> Another notable difference is the vertical alignment of certain types of inline content; many older browsers aligned images to the bottom border of their containing box, although the CSS specification requires that they be aligned to the baseline of the text within the box. In standards mode, Gecko-based browsers will align to the baseline, and in quirks mode they will align to the bottom.

Since the question is **why** this is happening, not how to solve it and there's already a few solutions in other answers, I won't add how to solve it.

Comment: Excellent.  I wish I could hand out two bounties because this is a very practical explanation of what is the most likely reason for this to happen, but I think I'll apply the bounty to Chris's answer for the code examples and explanation of the technical cause for why the browser adds the whitespace in the first place (inter-element-whitespace).  Thank you very much for your answer and you have my upvote.

Answer (score 3):

jsbin is misbehaving. It treats the [inter-element-whitespace](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/dom.html#inter-element-whitespace) differently.

http://jsbin.com/juterinu/3 behaves differently from http://jsfiddle.net/yfvU2

A file `ws.html` (http://jsfiddle.net/yfvU2)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>With inter-element-whitespace</title>
  <style type='text/css'>
      img { width: 350px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="no-ws.html">no-ws.html</a>
    <div id="images">
        <img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" />
        <img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" />
        <img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" />
        <img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" />
        <img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" />
        <img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

opened with Chrome or Firefox, shows a grid with space between the images.

### Why?

#### The horizontal whitespace

There are multiple whitespace characters between them. These get collapsed to a single whitespace. And then rendered.

#### The vertical whitespace

The [img-element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element) is by default `display: inline` and `vertical-align: baseline`. So what you see is some [leading](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#leading).

---

A file `no-ws.html` (http://jsfiddle.net/yfvU2/2/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Without inter-element-whitespace</title>
  <style type='text/css'>
      img {
          width: 350px;
          vertical-align: bottom;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="ws.html">ws.html</a>
  <div id="images"><img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" /><img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" /><img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" /><img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" /><img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" /><img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

will be rendered without whitespace.

Comment: Leading is pronounced /ˈlɛdɪŋ/, like the chemical element [lead](http://youtu.be/EzilaRwoMus?t=4m59s).

Comment: Come to think of it... This *still* doesn't explain why jsbin behaves the way it does....

Comment: **JS Bin** does not misbehaving, it runs the page on _Quirks mode_.

Comment: @dereli synonymous with misbehaving

Comment: I wouldn't say misbehaving, since you DO NOT add `<!DOCTYPE html>`, it doesn't mess with that, and the browsers activate _Quirks mode_. With this approach, JSFiddle is misbehaving as long as it prevents me activate Quirks mode.

Comment: Beautiful answer and nicely documented and supported with examples.  You and dereli have really helped me understand what was going on there.

Comment: Thanks @dereli and Chris I tried to add <!DOCTYPE html> at jsbin and indeed it made expected spacing to appear. Not sure what should be accepted answer here.

Comment: @dereli I like jsfiddle's exemplary approach to preventing litter. But you're right, passively allowing littering isn't misbehaving the way littering is misbehaving. I loathe the times I had to go to sources like ppk's quirksmode.org for daily WTF-relief.

Comment: @makc I'd accept dereli's one, because it helped *me* the most; it added the missing bit to my understanding. You should accept whatever worked best for *you*.

Answer (score 2):

The question yoy should ask is "why does the browser insert a gap between images, if I dont tell the browser to do so?"

Browsers do render a gap between images when there is a line break. Simples as that.

To solve it, just remove that line break and add the margin/padding by yourself. (http://jsbin.com/juterinu/5)

Comment: no, that's not the question, sigh. I need to edit it

Comment: Really? Look at http://jsbin.com/juterinu/5 and there is no gap in any way. Now at http://jsbin.com/juterinu/8 and there is a fixed gap. If that doesnt solve your problem, dont know how to help.

Comment: I don't have a problem, with gap or otherwise. I want to understand why there is no gap in case of 1 image per row.

Comment: Because there is a line break between images.

Comment: @Michael but that would mean there should be whitespace.  Resize the browser smaller to where there is only room for one image horizontally and you'll see the whitespace disappear

Comment: I just changed line break to space and it's exactly the same.

Comment: I saw that @JosephMarikle. That is just how broswers render it. I have no idea why. It has always been like that.

Comment: In http://jsfiddle.net/yfvU2/1/ the [inter-element-whitespace](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/dom.html#inter-element-whitespace) doesn't seem to matter for the way it is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by the line height.  Images are `display: inline` by default and therefor have a bit of space if they wrap.

See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html#t15

What you can do is either make them `display:block` and `float:left` or you can make them `display:inline-block` and give the parent container `line-height: 0; font-size: 0;`.  Safari seems to have an issue with font size being zero, so if you have to support it, you can use `font-size: 0.0001em;` instead.

Comment: why it does not happen if there is 1 image per row? (that's the question :)

Comment: It does.  At least in chrome.  If I widen the browser to have them all on one line, the container is still a few pixels taller than the images themselves.  If it's different for you, please include what browser/version/OS you are using

Comment: not in my chrome. 36.0.1955.2 canary mac. But same thing happens in FF.

Comment: and actually you need to shrink, not widen. until there is 1 image per row.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean now.  I misunderstood you.  I thought you mean one row.  I guess I don't know why browsers render it that way.  It's definitely having to do with whitespace of course, but it is odd that it drops it like that.

Comment: Setting the `img{vertical-align: bottom;}` or setting the `#images{line-height: 50%;}` will do the same; remove the leading between lines of images. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23792228/383793) for why.

Answer (score 0):

It happens due to the default spacing of the browser between words, you can try removing them and you'll see the gap disappears:

```
 <div>
    <img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" /><img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" /><img src="http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" />
</div>
```

The browser recognizes when it has to add a gap between words. When there's just one word per line, the browser doesn't add the gap.

You can do an analogy like this (when an **a** represents an image tag):

```
 <p>a a a a</p>
```

In the case above you have four words, therefore the browser adds the gap both between and below that line.

But, if you have this,

```
 <p>aaaa</p>
```

Then the browser, doesn't add any gap since it's just one word!

Comment: The question then is why doesn't it behave the same for a demo like this? http://jsbin.com/pajizagu/1 (the chrome emulate option next to console should help you get the screen narrow enough)

Comment: img-elements don't form words. Even img-elements *without* inter-element-whitespace *will* wrap. While real words like `aaaa` will only wrap when you set [`word-break: break-all;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-break-property)

Comment: [img](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element) is phrasing and flow content, just like a whole [text](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/dom.html#text-content) node. So the whole text node `a a a a` represents an img-element, if you will.

Answer (score 0):

I have been messing around in jsfiddle and think it may have something to do with the default border-thickness being medium, as setting the border-thickness to 0px fixes for me.  Other wise I don't know.  Hope this helps (although I doubt it) :)

Comment: Your self-doubt was right, in this case at least. ;-)

Comment: im not surprised, it was more off a guess based on messing around